# Why is my multiclass neural model not training (accuracy and loss staying same)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, multiclass-classification

I am learning neural networks. I get 98% accuracy with classical ML methods, so I think I made a coding error. The neural networks model is not learning.
Things I tried:

- Changing X and y to float64 or float32
- Normalizing data
- Changing the activation to "linear" or "relu"
- Removing `Flatten()`
- Adding hidden layers
- Using stochastic gradient descent as optimizer, instead of "adam".
- Changing the y label with another label

There are 9 labels in X_train and 8 different classes in y_train.

X_train:

[image]

y_train:

[image]

Code:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Input(shape=(9,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.compile(optimizer= 'adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Fitting:

[image]

I tried these lines by changing the target label. None of them help training the model. Some give "nan" loss, some go slightly up and down, but all of them are below 0.1% accuracy:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Input(shape=(9,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, name='dense1'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=24)
```

or this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Input(shape=(9,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='relu', name='relu1'))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', name='relu2'))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', name='relu3'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, name='dense1'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=20)
```

Comment: Add some hidden layers between the input layer and output layer.

Comment: I tried that with different activation functions.